# Delaying A Label Updated From Within connection:didReceiveData:data

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsurlconnection, nstextfield, performselector

I'm working on a download manager and I'm trying to update labels indicating the download speed and the percentage left.

It updates way too fast within connection:didReceiveData though, and using a performSelector and delaying it from that method doesn't work (it just delays it for that long before starting).

What should I do to update something like download speed or percentage left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to update the display as quickly as possible, just keep note of the time when you last updated it.  If the current time is not at least, say, 0.5 seconds since the last update, just don't update on this pass.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to see how you calculate speed and percentage but one approach will be :

1. Calculate time elapsed (in seconds) between two calls of `connection:didReceiveData`
2. Take the size of the current received data (let's call it `size`)
3. Sum total data size downloaded so far (lets call it `downloadedSize`)
4. `Speed = size / timeElapsed`
5. `Percentage = downloadedSize / Total data size` (Assuming you have it)
6. Convert to desired units
7. Update the labels (I do not see why you should delay here)

Comment: I think he wants to delay it to prevent the label from updating every frame, or at least so fast that the user can't read it...

Comment: Yeah, I just want to prevent the label from updating every frame.

Comment: Do you truncate your calculations ? (e.g display only 1.3 for 1.333333 etc ...)

Comment: Yeah, my calculations are truncated.